# How to overwrite a folder created in a function in R?

Tags: r, function

## Background

I have a function called `BP` (see R code below). This function: (1) creates a folder. (2) sets the folder as the working directory. (3) creates two plots. (4) saves each plot as a `png` file in the folder created created in (1).

## Question

If I run this function **more than 1 time**, I get the following error message:
`Warning message:
In dir.create(x) : 'C:\Users\...\Documents\Animation' already exists`

**How can I have this function "overwrite" the previous folder it creates after each run?**

```
BP = function(){
################################       # set working directory to "home"
setwd("~")
x <- paste0(getwd(), "/", "Animation") # Define the path & name of a new folder
dir.create(x)                          # create the new folder with name above
setwd(x)                               # set this just created folder as Work.Direc.

################################       # Create two plots save them as png in the above 
                                       # folder
for(i in 1:2) {

png(paste0("plot_", i, ".png"), width = 1200, height = 1300, res = 200)

plot( rnorm(1e2) )

dev.off()

   }

}

## Test Here:
BP()
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to create the folder new each time the function is called. Check if the folder exists using `file.exists` (despite its name it also works for folders). Only create the folder if it does not already exist.

If you need to empty the folder in each function call, you could do this using

```
file.remove(list.files(x, full.names = TRUE))
```